# VirtualBox: Start Firefox in Ubuntu via a Windows script?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, guest-os

I am using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu 12.04 as a guest in a Windows 7 host.  I would like execute a command in Windows that will launch Ubuntu's Firefox.  I tried VirtualBox's [VBoxManage guestcontrol](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol) function.  The command seems to do *something*, but nothing seems to happen in Ubuntu:

```
C:\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe guestcontrol MyVirtualMachineUbuntu exec --image "/usr/bin/firefox" --username bob --password password --wait-stdout --verbose
Waiting for guest to start process ...
Waiting for process to exit ...
Exit code=1 (Status=500 [successfully terminated])
```

The /usr/bin/firefox command works when I run it in Ubuntu.  Also, with guestcontrol, I can successfully call /bin/ls.  But I can't actually get a major program like Firefox to run.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Try it with `--username` instead of `--user`

Comment: @Simplexion: My script was using --username.  I mistyped it when writing the AskUbuntu post.  I've now fixed my post.  Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that it's not routed to the correct display?. Can you try: "DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/firefox"?.

Comment: @Javier Rivera: Thanks, your comment lead me to the correct solution.  I had to add the **--environment "DISPLAY=:0"** parameter and now it works like a charm.  If you want to formally answer this question, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that it's not routed to the correct display?

As you have found you can solve it using the --enviroment flag. The command should be:

```
VBoxManage.exe guestcontrol MyVirtualMachineUbuntu exec --image "/usr/bin/firefox" --username bob --password password --wait-stdout --verbose  --environment "DISPLAY=:0"
```